# Show order of a subgroup generated by $a$ is $n$

Tags: group-theory

Good day!

Let $a$ be in the group $G$ and assume $a^k=e$ for some positive integer $k$.
Let $n$ be the least positive integer such that $a^n=e$.

Show: $e,a,a^2,a^3,....,a^{n-1}$ are all distinct. Conclude that the order of the subgroup generated by $a$ is $n$.

Im slightly confused on where to get started, can some give me a pointer? (please dont just write that answer)

Thanks

Comment: I edited your question so that the $\LaTeX$ renders properly (and also added one period! ); you almost had it, but you left out the "\$" signs; you can check my edits to see what I meean.  Also note my use of braces for grouping:  "a^{n - 1}" yields $a^{n - 1}$; "a^(n -1)" yields $a^(n - 1)$; nice question, ***endorsed!!!*** !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try a proof by contradiction. Negate what we want to show, and formulate the result as an equation: there exist some $i,j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ with $i < j$ such that...?

Finally, manipulate this algebraic equation to find a positive integer $m < n$ such that $a^m = e$, which contradicts the minimality of $n$.

Comment: ahh, just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This little problem is so simple, yet so *essential*, that it is hard to say anything germane without giving away the farm, as it were; and furthermore, I'm not very good at the "hint" business.  So bear with me, if you will, if I say too much.

The key lies in the implications of the assumption that

$a^i = a^j\tag{1}$

for some

$0 \le i < j \le n - 1, \tag{2}$

for then we have, upon "multiplying" through by $a^{-i} = (a^i)^{-1}$,

$a^{j -i} = a^j a^{-i} = a^i a^{-i}$
$= a^i (a^i)^{-1} = e; \tag{3}$

but, subtracting $i$ from (2) we find that

$-i \le 0 < j - i$
$\le n - i - 1 < n, \tag{4}$

which speaks against the minimality of $n$ amongst all those positive integers $k$ with $a^k = e$; so the $a^i$, $0 \le i \le n - 1$, must be distinct.

Well, I guess I let too many cats out of the bag with that one; but at least Adriano's answer has already been accepted, so our OP The Physics Student has "seen it all before", as the saying goes.